# Unable to launch Manage Virtual Devices, Android Emulator Manager(AVD) and SDK Manager from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin Android and am facing a weird issue in Visual Studio. I am unable to click and open Manage Virtual Devices, Android Emulator Manager(AVD)and SDK Manager from Visual Studio(highlighted in the below image) although the same opens fine in Android Studio.(It doesn't throw any particular error or warning or doesn't even log anything in the output window, it just doesn't open) Can someone please suggest a solution?

[image]

Below is the output window logs when I open the project for your reference

```
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Users\d.dutta.chowdhury\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Java 6 SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8\JavaHome found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 7.0.2
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 22
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: F5AZFG14H791 unauthorized
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\d.dutta.chowdhury\.android\avd'
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\Users\DDUTTA~1.CHO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\android.BAT'
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 2 devices
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the image of your Android settings for VS? Open "Tools"  -> "Options", find the option "Xamarin" and then choose `Android Settings`.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I have updated my post to include the screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you sure your Android SDK location is right?

Comment: yes @GraceFeng-MSFT it is correct because Android Studio is also pointing to the same SDK location and SDK Manager is opening fine there without any issues

Comment: Try to go to the sdk/temp folder. There you will find a zip file with a name like "tools_r24.0.1-windows" (version number will be different).
Copy it to someplace and extract it. Inside the extracted folder you'll have a folder named 'tools'.
Copy that folder to sdk/ and replace the current tools folder in sdk/.

Comment: Sorry @GraceFeng-MSFT, there is no folder named 'temp' inside the sdk folder in my system